# Extracting html data to Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: python, html, excel

I am trying to use python to 'read' an html document and write the output to an excel spread sheet. the HTML file is a table of CU's (Cost Units, defined by being in all caps) and descriptions. I would like to have the CU's in one column and the corresponding descriptions in another. I have a global that stores parts of the text until it reaches a CU then puts the text into the correct column but for some reason the code wont complete the list of all CU's and it wont place the descriptions in the right place (places them one column down from applicable CU). Can anyone help me figure out what im doing wrong? Here is my code so far:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import xlwt
global wb
global ws
global cucounter
global textcounter
global tempcu
textstore = ""
cucounter = 0
textcounter = 0
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('A Test Sheet')
filename = 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.3\\Doc\\Page.html'
f = open(filename, "r").read()

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if data.isupper():
             try:
                  global cucounter
                  ws.write(cucounter, 1, data)
                  cucounter = cucounter + 1
                  wb.save('ElecTest.xls')
             except UnicodeDecodeError:
                  pass
        if data.isspace():
              pass
        else:
            try:
             global textstore
             textstore += str(data)
             if data.isupper():
                  global textstore
                  global textcounter
                  ws.write(textcounter, 2, textstore)
                  textcounter = textcounter + 1
                  textstore = ""
                  wb.save('ElectTest.xls')
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                  pass



parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(f)
```

unfortunately I cannot add my HTML file in the correct format (if i could the UnicodeDecodeError handling would make sense) but here is what i can copy:

Page    C/U     Description: 
M-M

```
EULBPIT     Excavate, backfill & tamp auger pit or primary splice hole.  Qty "1" per occurrence.  4'X4'X5' pit. 
EULBCOMPWHEEL   Wheel Compaction - Tamping with wheel, where initial lift is rolled, trench filled & crowned and rolled again and where additional traffic is expected in location assists with tamping. 
EULBCOMP85STD   85% Std. Proctor Compaction - Trench where subsidence is unsettled and probable due to nature of area, needing compaction equipment w/ 12” lifts, use in parking lots, adjacent to roadways & front lot line URD. 
EULBCOMP85MOD   85% Modified Proctor Compaction - Trenches under hard surfaces of roadway, more rigid than std, requiring compaction equipment w/ maximum 12” lifts, minimum12” lift from cable, soil and moisture content critical, hand test required also. 
EULBCOMP95STD   95% Std. Proctor Compaction - Used by most local jurisdictions, close to, but more than, 85% but needing more moisture, 12” lifts should be used and hand test for adequate moisture. 
EULBCOMP95MOD   95% Modified Proctor Compaction - Trenches under hard surfaces of roadway, more rigid than std, requiring compaction equipment w/ maximum 12” lifts, minimum12” lift from cable, soil and moisture content critical, hand test required. 
EULBCOMP    Compaction Test 
EULBSHORE   Shoring, 5’ high, 2-sided per ft per day 
EULBTHAWU   Thaw master/UG work:  Specify "1" in install column only.  Includes install, remove, lighting, & setting (2) burners with propane tank. 
EULBJACKHAMMER  Jackhammer:  Specify per sq ft X 4" deep.  Install column only. 
EULBHANDIKRETE  Handikrete.  Install only-Specify "1" per cu ft (1-bag). 
EUCDJACK4STPIPE     Jack 4" galvanized steel pipe - includes pipe & coupling.  Set up and dismantle jacking equipment.    Specify "1" per ft. 
EUCDJACK5STPIPE     Jack 5" galvanized steel pipe - includes pipe & coupling.  Set up and dismantle jacking equipment.  Specify "1" per ft. 
EUCDJACK6STPIPE     Jack 6" galvanized steel pipe - includes pipe & coupling.  Set up and dismantle jacking equipment.  Specify "1" per ft. 
EUCDIN-OUTJACK  Setting up & dismantle jacking equipment.  Includes digging & filling of pits.  Specify "1" per occurrence in the install column only. 
EUCDCASE24  Jack 24" casing--Specify "1" per ft - does not include pipe. 
EULBYSNOW   Snow removal.  Install column only; specify “1” for every 2 man-hours. 
EULBCLEANADJUST     Clean or adjust switchgear. Install only; specify “1” per occurrence. 
EULBUGLC    Install or remove line covers. Specify # of covers and occurrences. 
EULBLOWRCBL     Lowering cable - specify per linear ft.  Install column only. 
EULBGROUNDCBL   Install, remove or test for ground on cable.  Specify “1” per occurrence. 
EULBMOVECBL     Place terminator on stand-off or energized bushing.  Specify “1” per occurrence. Install column only. 
EULBPHASE-U     Phase-in UG conductor.  Install only; specify “1” per occurrence. 
EULBTRANSRISER  Transfer riser cable. Specify # of cables; install only:  specify “1” per occurrence. 
EULBLOCATEFAULT     Find UG cable fault - Install column only; specify “1” per occurrence. 
EULBCBLIDTESTER     Identify cable with impulse phaser.  Specify “1” per occurrence 
EULBPIERCECBL   Ground pierce cable - Install column only.  Specify “1” per occurrence. 
EULBSWITCH  Switch URD 600 A PMH gear.  Specify “1” per occurrence. 
EULBSWOIL   Switch-open & close OCR & Leads. Specify “1” per occurrence. 
EULBPDLCK   Padlock open and close.  Specify “1” per occurrence. 
EULBCOVERHOLE   Plywood to cover construction hole.  Specify “1’ per occurrence. 
EULBSCRTYFENCNG     Remove/replace/install security fencing (orange) around splice pit.  Specify “1” per occurrence. 
EULBDRTPKUP     Dirt pick-up: Load & haul excess dirt on site, per cu yd. 
EULBDRTPKPD     Dirt pick-up: Load & haul excess dirt off site, per cu yd. 
EULBROADBASE    Road base, labor only to install; specify "1" per cu yd.
```

```html
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15">
<meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 15">
<link rel=File-List href="Page_files/filelist.xml">
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:DocumentProperties>
  <o:Author>John Swordy</o:Author>
  <o:LastAuthor>John Swordy</o:LastAuthor>
  <o:Revision>1</o:Revision>
  <o:TotalTime>1</o:TotalTime>
  <o:Created>2017-02-15T16:44:00Z</o:Created>
  <o:LastSaved>2017-02-15T16:45:00Z</o:LastSaved>
  <o:Pages>2</o:Pages>
  <o:Words>600</o:Words>
  <o:Characters>3426</o:Characters>
  <o:Company>En Engineering</o:Company>
  <o:Lines>28</o:Lines>
  <o:Paragraphs>8</o:Paragraphs>
  <o:CharactersWithSpaces>4018</o:CharactersWithSpaces>
  <o:Version>16.00</o:Version>
 </o:DocumentProperties>
 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <o:AllowPNG/>
 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->
<link rel=themeData href="Page_files/themedata.thmx">
<link rel=colorSchemeMapping href="Page_files/colorschememapping.xml">
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  <w:TrackMoves>false</w:TrackMoves>
  <w:TrackFormatting/>
  <w:PunctuationKerning/>
  <w:ValidateAgainstSchemas/>
  <w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>
  <w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent>
  <w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>
  <w:DoNotPromoteQF/>
  <w:LidThemeOther>EN-US</w:LidThemeOther>
  <w:LidThemeAsian>X-NONE</w:LidThemeAsian>
  <w:LidThemeComplexScript>X-NONE</w:LidThemeComplexScript>
  <w:Compatibility>
   <w:BreakWrappedTables/>
   <w:SnapToGridInCell/>
   <w:WrapTextWithPunct/>
   <w:UseAsianBreakRules/>
   <w:DontGrowAutofit/>
   <w:SplitPgBreakAndParaMark/>
   <w:EnableOpenTypeKerning/>
   <w:DontFlipMirrorIndents/>
   <w:OverrideTableStyleHps/>
  </w:Compatibility>
  <m:mathPr>
   <m:mathFont m:val="Cambria Math"/>
   <m:brkBin m:val="before"/>
   <m:brkBinSub m:val="&#45;-"/>
   <m:smallFrac m:val="off"/>
   <m:dispDef/>
   <m:lMargin m:val="0"/>
   <m:rMargin m:val="0"/>
   <m:defJc m:val="centerGroup"/>
   <m:wrapIndent m:val="1440"/>
   <m:intLim m:val="subSup"/>
   <m:naryLim m:val="undOvr"/>
  </m:mathPr></w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:LatentStyles DefLockedState="false" DefUnhideWhenUsed="false"
  DefSemiHidden="false" DefQFormat="false" DefPriority="99"
  LatentStyleCount="371">
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="0" QFormat="true" Name="Normal"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 7"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 8"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 9"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 3"/>
```

If anyone could help me i would greatly appreciate it, thank you for your time! note: I am self taught and relatively new to python so I apologize in advance for code which might not be very nice to look at.

Comment: Can you post part of the html for reproducible example?

Comment: I exported a word doc to HTML in order to read it with python (I can only use built in modules). The HTML doesn't look different in word. What should I open it in in order to see the HTML?

Comment: Right click it and open with any web browser. Once it renders, go to page's source and post the HTML markup.

Comment: @Parfait I have added a few hundred lines at the top per your request, please let me know what else you may need.

Comment: Please post the beginning of file not lines in middle of document. We need declaration headers and then a few rows to help understand pattern. Also, why not in Excel under Open select html document to open it in spreadsheet? Excel would map contents to cells.

Comment: I have posted the first 100 lines of html. I cannot just open it in Excel as there are several images and the document is not all tables. I want to convert it into just tables, with CU and description. I am trying to create something that detects the CU's and takes the description from them. If there are extensive erroneous descriptions i can edit them out or filter them after.

Comment: Unfortunately, even this snippet isn't that helpful as you look to have a very large html file. I need to know enough to discern a pattern. Can you cut down the items in word document to few descriptions then export to html? I advise using web scraping Python libraries -BeautifulSoup, lxml, etc. to parse needed content for Excel import.